# resizing uiimage is flipping it?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to resize UIImage . i am taking the image and set its width to 640(for ex), and check the factor i had to use, and use it to the image height also .

Somehow the image is sometimes flips, even if it was portrait image, it becomes landscape.
I am probably not giving attention to something here ..

```
  //scale 'newImage'
    CGRect screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640.0, newImage.size.height* (640/newImage.size.width) );
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    [newImage drawInRect:screenRect];
    UIImage *scaled = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Pay attention to `image.orientation`, it may need to be transposed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i have the answer but its not her.
when i took the image from the assetLibrary i took it with :

```
CGImageRef imageRef = result.defaultRepresentation.fullResolution;
```

This flips the image, now i use :

```
CGImageRef imageRef = result.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage;
```

and the image is just fine .